# crontab confusion

Tags: linux, cron

I'm having trouble understanding the following cronjob from geeksforgeeks crontab page:

```
30 08 10 06 * /home/maverick/full-backup
```

I understand it executes at 8:30 AM on June 10th but the last * is throwing me off. Is this saying that it'll execute everyday of the week of June 10th? Or is that day of the week unknown and thus, the * is saying whatever day that ends up being, let it be.

Can someone clarify

Comment: You need the [`crontab guru`](https://crontab.guru/) for these situations where there's ambiguity.   :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, the `*` in the weekday column means that the day of the week is not relevant to the scheduling of this job.  The job will execute on June 10th of every year.  If you **did** have a day-of-week entry (say "Wednesday"), the job would on June 10th, and also on every Wednesday in June.  It's good to consult `man 5 crontab` on whatever system you're scheduling your job on, because `cron` implementations can vary.

Also, the man page may be either vague or intricate to read, such as:

> Commands  are executed by cron(8) when the minute, hour, and month of
> year fields match the current time, and when at least one of the two
> day fields (day of month, or day of week) match the current  time
> (see  ``Note''  below).

And:

> Note:  The  day  of a command's execution can be specified by two
> fields — day of month, and day of week.  If both fields are restricted
> (i.e., aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches
> the current  time.   For example, `30 4 1,15 * 5` would cause a
> command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus
> every Friday.

IMO, it is somewhat unfortunate that "when both fields are restricted" the restriction is actually **less** restrictive than when one field is restricted and the other field is a wildcard.

Compare:

```
30 08 10 06 * /home/maverick/full-backup
```

The job above will execute only on the 10th of June.

```
30 08 * 6 Wed /home/maverick/full-backup
```

The job above will execute every Wednesday in June.

```
30 08 10 06 Wed /home/maverick/full-backup
```

The job above will execute every Wednesday in June, and also on the 10th of June.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for clarifying! I didn't even know you could put  non-numbers in the weekday section!